# Auto connect to wifi on MacBook 2007

Tags: wireless, mac

I have gone through some of the documentation on getting the WiFi to work on a 2007 MacBook with a Broadcom BCM4321. The WiFi now works after running:

```bsh
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt install linux-firmware
```

However, I have to run `sudo modprobe b43` after each boot manually. Sometimes I have to run both:

```bsh
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
```

Is there any way to create a setting that will let me avoid doing this manually each time?

Answer (score 1):

I have added b43 to /etc/modules as suggested by Chili555, but still wasn't able to connect. Then I found a question from fhgshfdg on Ubuntu forums about finding b43 blacklisted in broadcom-sta-common.conf. Once I added the # to the line blacklisting b43 my wifi automatically connected on reboot.

Thank you to all who helped with this long search.

Comment: Excellent! Glad it's working! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have `bcmwl-kernel-source` that installed `broadcom-sta-common.conf` file blacklisting `b43`.

Remove it by

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Otherwise the file will be reverted on any `bvcwl-kernel-source` upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my 2007 MacBook working by going into the Driver Manager and deselecting the bcmwl driver.  That prevented it from generating the blacklist.
Afterwards, my system info using the inxi -Fxz command showed the driver to be Apple AirPort Extreme Driver:  b43-pci-bridge v